# Controls of controls

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently i am working on validations for my forms with mat-errors and hasErrors, everything is working fine till i need another control for a "inner" formgroup, what i mean is:

```html
prozessPersonenzuordnungenForm = new FormGroup({
    person: new FormGroup({
      firmenbezeichnung: new FormControl(),
      nameC: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      briefanrede: new FormControl('x'),
    }),
  });
```

I'm trying to reach the person.nameC validation. Im using this function:

```html
public hasError = (controlName: string, errorName: string) => {
    return this.prozessPersonenzuordnungenForm.controls[controlName].hasError(
      errorName
    );
  };
```

The problem is with this function i only reach the person FormGroup and not the nameC formControl. So i need another "deeper control".

Thats how my html looks like:

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="hasError('nameC', 'required')">Bitte gebe eine Person an!</mat-error>
```

I also tried it in html with person.nameC, but that was also not working. What would be a good way to reach my inner FormControl with my hasError function?

Comment: You will need some parsing mechanism of these dot-notated strings. For instance split by dot and iteratively take from `controls`

Comment: please use [get](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get) `this.prozessPersonenzuordnungenForm.get(controlName)`, not controls[]. this allow you use "dot notation" `hasError ('person.nameC', 'required')`. NOTE: if you use controls I imagine you need use some like `controls['person']['nameC']`

Answer (score 0):

Since your `controls` property is an object that has that simplified structure:

```
controls = {
    person: {
       nameC: {
         hasErrors: err => bool
       }
    }
}
```

You cannot say `controls["person.nameC"]` because there's no such property and these dot notations will not be automatically converted into nested property accessing.

This is left purely on your decision how to handle them. One idea is you to parse the dot-separated strings, split them and try to access the object in a loop.

For instance, if you split `"person.nameC"` string into an array by `.`, you will receive `arr = [ "person", "nameC" ]`

So let's examine the algorithm now:

```
let property = controls;
```

We start with the property from the furthest point - the whole control object. And one by one we are getting deeply:

```
property = property[ arr[0] ]
```

This will evaluate to `property = property["person"]` which will make the `property` variable to look like:

```
property = {
    nameC: {
       hasErrors: err => bool
    }
}
```

Now you can continue the same way

```
property = property[ arr[1] ]
```

Which will evaluate to `property = property["nameC"]` and the final result will be

```
property = {
    hasErrors: err => bool
}
```

Which is the one you want.

Of course, you don't need to manually to that, you can just loop through it:

```
let property: any = this.prozessPersonenzuordnungenForm.controls;
controlName.split('.').forEach(propertyKey => property = property[propertyKey]);

return property.hasError(errorName);
```

Comment: You need to fix your `forEach` implementation. It will break at deeper levels. You should assign property variable to the `FormGroup` itself and in the `forEach` you should use `property.controls[propertyKey]` to make it work.

Comment: Use [get](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get)

Comment: thx, found a better a way. You can see it in my answer :)

Comment: It will work only on two levels this way? :)

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your help guys, but i found a much easier way!

Thats my working solution:

```html
public hasError = (controlName: string, deepControlName:string,  errorName: string) => {
    return this.prozessPersonenzuordnungenForm.controls[controlName].get(deepControlName)?.hasError(errorName);
  };
```

For example, i can use it now like this:

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="hasError('person', 'nameC', 'required')"> </mat-error>
```